# Export-Csv : The specified wildcard character pattern is not valid: System.Object[]

Tags: powershell

I've created a PS function which generates a CSV using a path provided as a parameter.

A preceding function creates the path on the C: drive if it doesn't already exist.

If the path already exists the file is saved fine. However,  if the directory is created before the CSV is exported then I get the error:

```
Export-Csv : The specified wildcard character pattern is not valid: System.Object[]
```

If I write out the path it returns as: System.Object[]\filename.csv

The input parameter is a String, the path name returned by the preceding function is a String and when I use $OutputDirectory.GetType() I get a String with base type System.Object.

When I use a literal string then function works fine, even when a new directory is created. It's just when the path returned by the function is used as the value for param $OutputDirectory that I get this error.

```
Function New-Output{

[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [object]
    $ResultsObject,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $OutputDirectory
)

$OutputDirectory.GetType() # String / BaseType = System.Object

$OutputFileName = Join-Path $OutputDirectory.ToString() -ChildPath "\output.csv"

# output the results
$ResultsObject.Node | Select-Object total, errors, failures | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFileName - 
NoTypeInformation

}
```

So when a directory is first created Export-Csv thinks that $OutputDirectory is type System.Object.

Here's the function which creates the directory. This seems to work fine and returns a string:

```
Function New-TestResultsOutputDirectory{

[CmdletBinding()]
[OutputType([String])]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [object]
    $ResultsObject
)

# set the test name, date and time values from the test-results node
$testSuiteDirectory = Split-Path ($ResultsObject.Node.name).ToString()

# set the attributes for the output directory
$testDate = $testResults.Node.date.ToString().Replace("-","")
$testTime = $testResults.Node.time.ToString().Replace(":","")
$testSuiteName = (Split-Path (Split-Path ($ResultsObject.Node.name).ToString() -Parent) -Leaf).Replace(".","_")
$resultsDirectory = ($testSuiteName + "_" + $testDate + "_" + $testTime).ToString()
$outputDirectory = (Join-Path $testSuiteDirectory -ChildPath $resultsDirectory).ToString()

# check if the output path exists
$outputPathExists = Test-Path $outputDirectory

# create the results output path if it does not exists
if(!$outputPathExists){

    # create the directory
    New-Item -Path $outputDirectory -ItemType "directory"

    # check if the directory has been created
    $outputPathExists = Test-Path $outputDirectory

    while($outputPathExists -eq $false){

        # wait for 5 seconds
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

        # recheck if the directory has been created
        $outputPathExists = Test-Path $outputDirectory

    }

}

return $outputDirectory
}
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: show example of the values for the `$OutputDirectory` and  `$OutputFileName` variables

Comment: C:\Temp\SIT_20200515_124311\Summary.csv

Comment: That function does not test if the output directory exists, nor does it create that folder if it doesn't exist. You should implement that before constructing a target filename.

Comment: If `$OutputDirectory` string is `C:\Temp\SIT_20200515_124311\Summary.csv`, then it is a complete path to a file, not the directory, which should only be `C:\Temp\SIT_20200515_124311`

Comment: @Theo the path is the value of $OutputFileName. I do have a function which creates the directory and checks it exists before returning the path.

Comment: Also, to reiterate, I only get the error if the directory does not exist and it is being created for the first time. I don't think it's a timing issue as I added a long sleep after the New-Item command and it made no difference, and the while loop is never entered.

Comment: is there a reason for all the very strange `.ToString()` calls? most of those objects should return a string OR be able to give a string by using `$Var.ParameterName` to get the value. i suspect you have some very strange thing showing up as a result of those ... extremely peculiar ... calls to stringify your objects.

Comment: The  ToString() conversions was to try and resolve this error.

Comment: Use `$null = New-Item -Path $outputDirectory -ItemType "directory"` (because `New-Item` isn't silent).

Comment: @JosefZ If possible please can you add a comment to the answer to explain why this works. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$null = New-Item -Path $outputDirectory -ItemType "directory"`

Thanks to @JosefZ

> "because New-Item isn't silent" - it would be helpful to have a more detailed explanation on what this means.

Answer (score 0):

From [About Return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return?view=powershell-7): *… In PowerShell, values can be returned even if the return keyword is not used. **The results of each statement are returned** …*

From [About Functions OutputTypeAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_outputtypeattribute?view=powershell-7): *… The OutputType attribute value is only a documentation note. It is not derived from the function code or compared to the actual function output. …*

An illustrative script:

```
Function CreateDirWrong {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([String])]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$Path='.',
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$ChildPath
    )
    $outputDirectory = Join-Path -Path $Path -ChildPath $ChildPath
    if ( -not (Test-Path -Path $outputDirectory )) {
        New-Item -Path $outputDirectory -ItemType Directory
    }
    return $outputDirectory
}

Function CreateDirGood {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([String])]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$Path='.',
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$ChildPath
    )
    $outputDirectory = Join-Path -Path $Path -ChildPath $ChildPath
    if ( -not (Test-Path -Path $outputDirectory )) {
        $null = New-Item -Path $outputDirectory -ItemType Directory
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
    }
    return $outputDirectory
}
# clean up
Remove-Item -Path .\SO61912603w, .\SO61912603g -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$ReturnWrong = CreateDirWrong -ChildPath 'SO61912603w'
$ReturnGood  = CreateDirGood  -ChildPath 'SO61912603g'
Get-Variable Return* -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Select-Object -Property Name,
        @{N='Type'; E={$_.Value.GetType().FullName}}, Value |
    Out-Default
'… Compare actual $Return* variable types (above)'
'… and their declared types (below):'
Get-Command -Name CreateDir* |
    Select-Object -Property Name, OutputType | Out-Default
# clean up
Remove-Item -Path .\SO61912603w, .\SO61912603g -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

And its **output**: `D:\PShell\SO\61912603.ps1`

```
Name        Type            Value
----        ----            -----
ReturnGood  System.String   .\SO61912603g
ReturnWrong System.Object[] {D:\PShell\SO61912603w, .\SO61912603w}


… Compare actual $Return* variable types (above)
… and their declared types (below):

Name           OutputType
----           ----------
CreateDirGood  {System.String}
CreateDirWrong {System.String}
```

Here's an explanatory example for my "**… because `New-Item` isn't silent**" statement (unlike e.g. `Start-Sleep` which outputs nothing):

```
Get-Command -Name New-Item, Start-Sleep |
    Select-Object -Property Name, OutputType
```

> ```
> Name        OutputType                         
> ----        ----------                         
> New-Item    {System.String, System.IO.FileInfo}
> Start-Sleep {}
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Makes a bit more sense now. The part that I’ve not quite grasped is that I’m not explicitly returning any output from New-Item. I set $outputDirectory as a string and this is returned by the function. How does New-Item influence the return of $outputDirectory?

Comment: @Lymedo The return of `$outputDirectory` isn't affected. Again: _The results of each statement are returned_. Hence, output from `New-Item` cmdlet is returned _along with_ the `$outputDirectory` string **if not assigned to a variable** (something like `$auxiliary = New-Item …`) **or thrown away** (like `$null = New-Item …` or  like `New-Item … | Out-Null`). No magic here.